# Git problem after OS Ventura

Tags: terminal, mac, xcode, iterm

After upgrading to OS-Ventura I keep getting the same error:
 `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`.

I have tried `xcode-select --install` and `sudo xcode-select --reset` but they do not work since my terminal quits before doing anything. It simply says `[Process completed]` after executing either of the lines above.

Comment: You need to reinstall the CLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences should be offering a software update for Command Line Tools. Some times it even offers multiple different versions. If so, accept those and install.

If you are not offered an update in Software Update, install Xcode.app again and install command line tools.

Comment: If you install XCode, you don't need the CLT, the compiler and the tools are already part of XCode.

Comment: Interesting, I’ve experienced issues installing Xcode on top of older Xcode that offered newer CLT installs I needed to install.

Comment: This works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `sudo xcode-select -r`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some context to your answer.  What does the command do?

Comment: resets xcode config to default

Comment: This is not meant to be pedantic...the idea behind the site is to have good answers to questions.  Please take a moment to review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for some guidance.  This helps with future visitors/readers who many not fully understand the solution to their problem.  It also helps with earning reputation and further priviliges.

Comment: well if i understood why it works i would’ve said  but point taken thank you

Answer (score 0):

just run to install xcode after the Ventura update from the Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: The question said they tried this.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem after my update to macOS Ventura and I went through brew, typing in my terminal `brew install --cask xcodes` and everything was back to normal.

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/xcodes#default